# Setting up Django admin in visual studio

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, visual-studio, web

When I make django project on visual studio there is no admin page.
Can anyone help me how to set up the admin page in visual studio?
I mean the admin.py page. Which commands should be run.
I have tried many methods but none succeeded.

thanks

Saeed

Comment: What do you mean by that, do you want to create a `superuser` or `register a model` to the admin page?

Comment: Yes, I want to create superuser and register model to the admin page.

Answer (score 2):

I just started learning Django so this is not as in depth as I would like and was also fairly confused on how to procede when I didn't see it either. After an embarrassing amount of research... Turns out you don't really need the admin.py file to *initially* access the admin page. You will need one eventually though. So specifically for VS:

1. make sure you uncommented (or that these exist) in the urls.py:

   ```
   from Django.contrib import admin
   from Django.conf.urls import include
   #and either, where the admin.py file exists
   import name_of_another_app.admin
   # or
   admin.autodiscover() 
   urlpatterns = [
   … # blah, blah, blah
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   ]
   ```
2. Now you will need to create a superuser by right clicking the Project (under the solution)

   > > go into the python menu and click 'Django create superuser ...' and follow the instructions to input a user, email, password.

[screenshot of a new project following VS tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikxLx.png)

in the screenshot there isn't an admin.py file anywhere, however once you run the web server and edit the url by adding /admin to the end you will be able to log in and access the admin page.

If you want an actual admin.py file, you will either have to create one yourself, or as you create new apps an empty one will be generated for you. There you can begin to customize what you need in the admin page.

Hopefully this helps someone!!

Answer (score 0):

To create a superuser:

`python manage.py createsuperuser` choose a username and create a password.

To register a model in the Django site admin, go to the `admin.py` inside your app and write:

`admin.site.register(<ModelName>)`.

Don't forget to import your model: `from .models import <ModelName>`.

After that, should be able to login in the django site admin and see your model.

Comment: I've created a super use but when I run the server /admin/

Comment: After you run your server `python manage.py runserver` you can go to the Django site admin >  `http://localhost:8000/admin/` enter your username and password. If you have registered the model, it will be visible there.

Comment: But there is no admin.py page!! even after creating superuser!! what is wrong

Comment: Aso my terminal does not accept any of Django command! Where should I install Python? is it like other programs or it's it needs a specific place?

Answer (score 0):

Really frustrating issue! Go into command prompt and paste python manage.py startapp hello. A new folder will appear called 'hello' (obv name folder to what you want). This will contain all you need with admin included.

Answer (score 0):

**In Visual Studio**, in project templates instead of making Django web project, I made Django blank project and then added Django app to the project.